# Como deletar nó em lista ligada?

Tags: c#

Como deletar o valor do meio de uma lista ligada C#

Classe de Elementos;

```
public class NoLista
{
    public float info;
    public NoLista proximo;

    //construtor para passar valor ao elemento
    public NoLista(int valor)
    {
        this.info = valor;
        this.proximo = null;
    }
}
```

Classe para as operações

```
    public class Lista
{
    private NoLista inicio;
    public Lista()
    {
        this.inicio = null;
    }

    public void Remover(float valor)
    {
        if (this.inicio == null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("o Valor preenchido nao existe na Lista");
        }
        else
        {
            NoLista antecesser = this.inicio;

            if(antecesser.info != valor)
            {
                 antecesser = this.inicio.proximo;
            }

            //aqui quero deletar o valor


        }
    }
```

Comment: Mostre o que já fez, e indique com o que está tendo problema.

Comment: `var numeros = new LinkedList<int>(new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 });
numeros.Remove(3);` 

Comment: pronto, implementei a pergunta.

Answer (score 0):

Sua pergunta não está muito clara.

O que eu entendi foi que você tem uma lista com 4 elementos e deseja remover um específico. Isso pode ser feito da seguinte maneira:

```
var lista = new List<int> {1, 2, 3, 4}; //Criar um list com 4 elementos
lista.Remove(3); //Remover o item com o valor "3"
```

Answer (score 0):

O algoritmo é mais ou menos assim:

"Seja `NoAtual` o primeiro nó da lista.

Enquanto `NoAtual` não for nulo:

Se o valor guardado por `NoAtual` for diferente do valor que quero remover, `NoAtual` recebe o sucessor de `NoAtual`. Em seguida, `continue`.

Caso contrário (ou seja, se o valor guardado for igual ao que eu quero remover):

Se `NoAtual` é o primeiro da lista, faça o `inicio` da lista apontar para o sucessor de `NoAtual`. Destrua `NoAtual`. Encerre.

Caso contrário (caso não seja o primeiro da lista), então o sucessor do antecessor de `NoAtual` passa a ser o sucessor de `NoAtual`. Destrua `NoAtual`. Encerre."

Em C#, não é necessário destruir explicitamente os elementos que você quer apagar, pois o ambiente de execução cuida disso para você.

Fica como exercício para você descobrir quais variáveis você vai ter que guardar para conseguir ligar as referências do antecessor com o sucessor.

Answer (score 0):

Uma vez que você encontre o No com o valor desejado, você só precisa atualizar a propriedade próximo do No anterior ou a propriedade inicio da lista.

Você não precisa apagar o No, apenas destrua qual quer referencia a ele, então deixe que o GC decida quando e como dá um fim nele.

```
public void Remover(float valor)
{
    if (this.inicio == null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("A lista está vazia");
        return;
    }

    //buscando o nó com o valor informado.
    var noAnterior = default(NoLista);
    var noAtual = this.inicio;
    do
    {
        if (noAtual.info == valor)
        {
            break;
        }
        noAnterior = noAtual;
        noAtual = noAtual.proximo;
    } while(noAtual != null);

    if (noAtual == null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("O valor não foi encontrado");
        return;
    }

    //nó a ser apagado é o no inicial, então setar o proximo o como o inicial.
    if (noAnterior == null)
    {
        this.inicio = noAtual.proximo;
    }
    else
    {
        noAnterior.proximo = noAtual.proximo;
    }
}
```

Você pode ver o exemplo acima em funcionamento acessando o seguinte [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ZSZp5K)